# Is there a way to get a permanent access token on BOX API v2

Tags: box-api

We know that BOX API v1 can get a permanent auth_token, but BOX API v2 which use Oauthv2 does not, and it only valid for 1hour for the access_token and 14days for the refresh_token(afaik).

I have this application that a single form-owner integrates with BOX.
For example I have a form created that every submission will be uploaded to BOX( of course this will be set up, and it uses BOX API v1 )

Users that will submit the form will use the access_token created by the form owner.
We don't know if what time the next submission is. So by that time, the access_token might get expire or the refresh_token as well.

Can anyone enlighten me, how to refresh the token? on each user submission? or what?

BOX API v1 is no problem here, it works perfectly but because API v1 is going to die on Dec, I have to plan now to convert it to v2, but Box api v2 has a token expiration.

Thanks

Comment: How did you refresh your token? Is there any API endpoint where you could refresh the token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and the solution I got was
To write a schedule task or corn job which will
Always keep the refresh and access token alive

Create a backed task which will run say every 
13 th day and use the preexisting  refresh token
To get a new refresh token

Comment: I think I have to stick with this solution then. Thank you!

Comment: i presume the new one has to be recorded to the DB if one is being used? On the Java API, I couldn't see how to detect a change.

Comment: @alok How did you refresh your token? Is there any API endpoint where you could refresh the token?